# Finding a property within a JavaScript array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, lodash

I have a JavaScript array which looks like this. The array contain object of different type.

```
[
    {
        "className": "XXXX",
        "targets": [
            0,
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4
        ],
        "sClass": "lg" 
    },
    {
        "iDataSort": 0
    },
    {
        "targets": [
            9,
            10
        ]
    },
    {
        "targets": [
            7,
            8,
            9,
            10,
            11,
            12,
            13,
            14,
            15
        ],
        "visible": false,
        "bVisible": false
    }
]
```

I want to search an element (object) in this array which contains two property with name `targets` and `visible` and once I find this object, I want to update the value of `targets` property.

What is the most efficient way to do this? Is it possible to use underscorejs or lodash for this?

Comment: Do you want to update the *first* such item or *all* such items?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501371/get-an-object-from-array-which-contains-a-specific-value

Comment: @IngoBürk: Only the first instance :) Very good question :)

Comment: @SharpCoder Then you have to watch out using the answer you accepted. Simply returning from the inner function will not prevent updating *all* such items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `$.each()` along with `.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)` at this context,

```
$.each(test, function (i, val) {
    if (val.hasOwnProperty("visible") && val.hasOwnProperty("targets")) {
        alert('yes..')
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s6w2cfzt/1/)